# Visual Studio 2015 can't (re)build fast - file locked

Tags: build, visual-studio-2015, locked-files

It's the famous

> "Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\MVP.exe" to "bin\Debug\MVP.exe". The
>   process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\MVP.exe' because it is being
>   used by another process."

message again. Visual Studio Enterprise on Windows 7 64bit. These are the steps to reproduce:

1. I build a solution (F6) Build finishes with no errors.
2. I notice a small annoyance so I quickly correct it
3. Press F6 to build again, but now the build can't execute due to
   aforementioned error.
4. Wait for 30 seconds
5. Now I can build again

So why keeps VS this file locked for so long after the build has been completed? What can I do?

**EDIT**

So I check it with Process Explorer (which you can download from Microsoft). The file is sometimes in use by the process called "system". It's in use for about 30 seconds. Then "system" releases it, though the executable I'm testing might be still running. But basically, as long as process "system" is having a hold on that file, one cannot build the solution. So why is that process holding that file for 30 seconds after some rebuilds (or running it)?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

I had "Application User Experience Service" disabled. By enabling the service, the compiled file in Visual Studio 2015 won't be hijacked by the **system-process** (PID 4) anymore. Problem solved.

**Other Stuff**

First I tried to fiddle with the indexing service by excluding the project folder(s). I also fiddled with index throttling. Running stuff from an overclocked I7 3820 with SSD obviously this didn't have any effect.